# Naming a nameless (ANONYMOUS) block in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, block, anonymous

I'm facing a really weird glitch. So, I'm trying to add a block to my home with the following code `{{block type="core/template" name="ves_random_products" template="page/RandomProducts.phtml"}}` which works great, show random products from a collection etc, piece of cake.

The thing is now I'm using a full page cache extension and I need to make this block dynamic, the problem is Magento dosen't seems to take "ves_random_products" as the block name and when the page is loaded, my block has no name (nameless/anonymous), when I do a `var_dump(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getAllBlocks());` the name of the block shows as "ANONYMOUS_0". And the weirdest thing is that inside the `Mage::app()->getLayout()->getAllBlocks()` I can see the parameter "name" with the value "ves_random_products". The full output for the var_dump is:

```
array(1) {
  ["ANONYMOUS_0"]=&gt;
  object(Mage_Core_Block_Template)#243 (31) {
    ["_viewDir":protected]=&gt;
    string(32) "/var/www/html/magento/app/design"
    ["_viewVars":protected]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_baseUrl":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_jsUrl":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_allowSymlinks":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_template":protected]=&gt;
    string(25) "page/RandomProducts.phtml"
    ["_nameInLayout":protected]=&gt;
    string(12) "ANONYMOUS_0"
    ["_layout":protected]=&gt;
    object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout)#192 (15) {
      ["_update":protected]=&gt;
      object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update)#191 (7) {
        ["_elementClass":protected]=&gt;
        NULL
        ["_packageLayout":protected]=&gt;
        NULL
        ["_cacheId":protected]=&gt;
        NULL
        ["_cachePrefix":protected]=&gt;
        NULL
        ["_updates":protected]=&gt;
        array(0) {
        }
        ["_handles":protected]=&gt;
        array(7) {
          ["default"]=&gt;
          int(1)
          ["cms_page"]=&gt;
          int(1)
          ["STORE_fsview"]=&gt;
          int(1)
          ["THEME_frontend_default_ves_superstore"]=&gt;
          int(1)
          ["cms_index_index"]=&gt;
          int(1)
          ["page_one_column"]=&gt;
          int(1)
          ["customer_logged_out"]=&gt;
          int(1)
        }
        ["_subst":protected]=&gt;
        array(2) {
          ["from"]=&gt;
          array(2) {
            [0]=&gt;
            string(11) "{{baseUrl}}"
            [1]=&gt;
            string(17) "{{baseSecureUrl}}"
          }
          ["to"]=&gt;
          array(2) {
            [0]=&gt;
            string(26) "http://mystore.com/"
            [1]=&gt;
            string(27) "https://mystore.com/"
          }
        }
      }
      ["_blocks":protected]=&gt;
      *RECURSION*
      ["_output":protected]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_area":protected]=&gt;
      string(8) "frontend"
      ["_helpers":protected]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_directOutput":protected]=&gt;
      bool(false)
      ["_xml":protected]=&gt;
      object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)#40 (0) {
      }
      ["_cacheId":protected]=&gt;
      NULL
      ["_cacheTags":protected]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
      ["_cacheLifetime":protected]=&gt;
      NULL
      ["_cacheChecksum":protected]=&gt;
      bool(false)
      ["_cacheSaved":protected]=&gt;
      bool(false)
      ["_cache":protected]=&gt;
      NULL
      ["_elementClass":protected]=&gt;
      string(30) "Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element"
      ["_xpathExtends":protected]=&gt;
      string(13) "//*[@extends]"
    }
    ["_parent":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_alias":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_anonSuffix":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_children":protected]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_sortedChildren":protected]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_childrenHtmlCache":protected]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_childGroups":protected]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_request":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_messagesBlock":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_isAnonymous":protected]=&gt;
    bool(true)
    ["_parentBlock":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_frameOpenTag":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_frameCloseTag":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_sortInstructions":protected]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_factory":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_app":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_data":protected]=&gt;
    array(5) {
      ["type"]=&gt;
      string(13) "core/template"
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(19) "ves_random_products"
      ["template"]=&gt;
      string(25) "page/RandomProducts.phtml"
      ["block_params"]=&gt;
      array(3) {
        ["type"]=&gt;
        string(13) "core/template"
        ["name"]=&gt;
        string(19) "ves_random_products"
        ["template"]=&gt;
        string(25) "page/RandomProducts.phtml"
      }
      ["module_name"]=&gt;
      string(9) "Mage_Core"
    }
    ["_hasDataChanges":protected]=&gt;
    bool(true)
    ["_origData":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_idFieldName":protected]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["_isDeleted":protected]=&gt;
    bool(false)
    ["_oldFieldsMap":protected]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["_syncFieldsMap":protected]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying with no sucess to make this block to have a name, what am I doing wrong? Looked all over the internet and It seems that I'm the only one facing this problem (?!). Weird. Is this a core glitch? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but since it looks like you're adding the block inside a CMS I think the name is disregarded. You might need it saved in a layout XML for it to actually count as named.

Either way I do not think just naming it will solve your main issue, what you need is hole-punching the FPC - using this method will probably help:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35140/static-block-fpc-hole-punch